# double(<character>) gives different result in MATLAB and Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

MATLAB ([documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html)):

```
>> double('α')    
ans =    
   945
```

Octave 4.0.0, Ubuntu 16.04 ([documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/double.html)):

```
>> double('α')
ans =    
   206   177
```

Why do I get different results?

<sub>**Note**: 'α' is a greek lowercase alpha.</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because the default encoding in MATLAB is `'US-ASCII'` (can be different depending on [Locale settings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/how-the-matlab-process-uses-locale-settings.html)) while in Octave, it is `'UTF-8'`.

To confirm, here is the result from MATLAB:

```
>> unicode2native('α', 'UTF-8')

ans =

  1×2 uint8 row vector

   206   177
```

You can check your encoding with `feature` or [`slCharacterEncoding()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/slcharacterencoding.html) :

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet')
```

or

```
slCharacterEncoding()
```

---

According to Mathworks, you can [change your encoding](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/slcharacterencoding.html) with:

```
slCharacterEncoding(encoding)
```

I didn't have much luck in changing the encoding and getting the same results afterwards. It could be a bug.